# sed apply two search conditions to a single line and then substitute

Tags: regex, sed, logical-operators, logical-and

Id like to do do the following substitution

```
sed 's/$/)/' python2.py
```

with the condition that a line contains `print(` but it may not contain `print("""`.

A line that it should **not** match would be

```
print("""Some multi line text etc...
```

While lines like this should be matched

```
print("Some single line text"
```

Now its easy to match one or to exclude the other but i fail to combine both conditions into one command. For example

```
sed -ne '/print(/s/$/)/p' python2.py
```

Does match all lines with `print(` but also the ones which i would like to omit with
`print("""`. On the other hand i can skip all lines with `print("""` with

```
sed -ne /print("""/! s/$/)/p python2.py
```

But that includes all other lines even those without `print(`. Is there any way to combine both conditions such that the substition is only applied when both conditions are true for a line ?

As a note :

I am aware that i can do two sed runs where i first do the substitutions for all `print(` lines and then do a second sed run where i remove the newly substituted `)` only in the `print("""` lines. I'd like to know if it is possible to do it in one go so that is not an answer that i am looking for.

Comment: What if a line is already `print("Some single line text")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed, you can use

```sh
sed '/print("""/!{/print("/s/$/)/}' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/A3PM39).

*Details*:

- `/print("""/!` - if `print("""` is found, skip the line
- `{/print("/s/$/)/}` - else, if line contains `print("`, replace the end of line with `)`.

Comment: Nothing here is hard to do in standard `sed` either. Some `sed` dialects will insist on statement terminators before or after the curly brackets. You can avoid that by changing the `!` to a `b` and then you don't need the curlies.

Comment: Works as intended. The curly braces syntax was what i was missing.

Comment: Aha, `sed '/print("""/b;/print("/s/$/)/'` will work, too.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `sed` that ignore lines that already have a closing `)`:

```sh
cat file
print("""Some multi line text etc...
print("Some single line text"
print("Some single ""line text"
print("Some single line text")

sed '/print("""/!s/print(".*[^)]$/&)/' file
print("""Some multi line text etc...
print("Some single line text")
print("Some single ""line text")
print("Some single line text")
```

Pattern `print(".*[^)]$` matches a line with test from `print("` with a non-`)` character in the end. `&)` places `)` at the end of matching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
print("""Some multi line text etc...
print("Some single line text"

$ sed 's/print("[^"].*/&)/' file
print("""Some multi line text etc...
print("Some single line text")
```

If not then please edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output that includes cases this doesn't work for.